# Why does apply throw a CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED-ERROR on a large list?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

```
(apply #'+ (loop for i from 1 to x collect 1))
```

works if `x` has value `253391`, but fails with a `(SB-KERNEL::CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED-ERROR)` on `253392`*. This is orders of magnitude smaller than `call-arguments-limit`**.

Is recursion exhausting the stack? If so, is it in `apply`? Why hasn't it been optimized out?

---

*Also interesting, `(apply #'max (loop for i from 1 to 253391 collect 1))` throws the error, but `253390` is fine.

**`call-arguments-limit` evaluates to 4611686018427387903 (with the help of `format`'s `~R`, it turns out this is <sub>four quintillion six hundred eleven quadrillion six hundred eighty-six trillion eighteen billion four hundred twenty-seven million three hundred eighty-seven thousand nine hundred three</sub>)

Comment: Clarification: I really am looking for possible implementation reasons for why this causes a stack exhausted error. What is on the stack and why? I am not actually interested in better ways to perform list processing.

Comment: what kind of recursion would you expect in APPLY? I would expect none.

Comment: I would also expect none, which is why I was confused. See my answer below for what actually ends up on the stack, which in hindsight is very obvious. I'm just too used to thinking "stack overflow == bad recursion", I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's causing the stack exhaustion?

Though recursion is often a likely culprit for stack exhaustion, that is not true in this case. According to the [SBCL Internals Manual](http://www.sbcl.org/sbcl-internals/Full-Calls.html):

> In full call, the arguments are passed creating a partial frame on the stack top and storing stack arguments into that frame.

Each generated list element is stored in the new stack frame, quickly exhausting the stack. Presumably, passing SBCL a larger value through `–control-stack-size` would increase this practical limit to the number of arguments that can be passed in a function call.

## Why is `call-arguments-limit` so much larger than the practical limit?

An [SBCL mailing list response](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/mailman/message/9286212/) to someone with a similar problem explains why the practical limit of the stack size isn't reflected in `call-arguments-limit`:

> The condition you're seeing here is not due to a fundamental implementation limitation, but rather because of the particular choice of stack size that someone chose -- if the stack size were bigger, this call of yours would not error.  [...] Consider that, given our strategy of passing excess arguments on the stack, that the actual maximum number of arguments passable at any given time depends on the program state, and isn't in fact a constant.

Spec says that [`call-arguments-limit` must be a constant](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm), so SBCL seems to have [defined it as `most-positive-fixnum`](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/279038f15981bceccd67a18c8c36c44751a68d92/src/compiler/early-c.lisp#L19).

There are and a [couple of](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1388286) [bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/309096) discussing the issue, and a [TODO](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/279038f15981bceccd67a18c8c36c44751a68d92/src/compiler/x86-64/values.lisp#L131) in the source suggesting that at least one contributor feels it should be reduced to a less absurd value:

```
;; TODO: Reducing CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT to something reasonable to
;; allow DWORD ops without it looking like a bug would make sense.
;; With a stack size of about 2MB, the limit is absurd anyway.
```

**SBCL's particular way of implementing `call-arguments-limit` might have room for improvement and could lead to unexpected behaviour, but it does follow ANSI spec.**

The practical limit varies depending on the space remaining on the stack, so defining `call-arguments-limit` according to this value would not obey the spec requirement for a constant value.

Answer (score 5):

> parameters that can be passed to a function in SBCL

You don't pass *parameters*. You pass *arguments*.

```
(defun foo (x y) (list x y))
```

`x` and `y` are *parameters* of the function `foo`.

```
(foo 20 22)
```

`20` and `22` are *arguments* in a call of the function `foo`.

See the variables `call-arguments-limit` and `lambda-parameters-limit`.

**SBCL and call-arguments-limit**

If a function can't nearly handle the claimed number of arguments, then this looks like a bug in `SBCL`. You might want to report this bug. Maybe they need to change the value of `call-arguments-limit`.

**Testing**

`APPLY` is one way to test it.

Another:

```
(eval (append '(drop-params)
               (loop for i from 1 to 2533911 collect 1)))
```

One can also use FUNCALL with a number of arguments spread out.

**Why does a limit exist?**

The Common Lisp standard was written to allow efficient implementations on various different computers. It was thought that some machine-level function calling implementations only support limited number of arguments. The standard says the number of supported arguments can be as low as `50`. Actually some implementations have a relatively low number of supported arguments.

Thus `apply` in Common Lisp is not a tool for *list processing*, but to call functions with computed arglists.

**For list and vector processing use REDUCE, instead of APPLY**

If we want to sum all numbers in a list, replace

```
(apply #'+ list)     ; don't use this
```

with

```
(reduce #'+ list)    ; can handle arbitrary long lists
```

**Recursion**

> apply is a non-optimized recursive function

I cannot see why the function `APPLY` should use recursion.

For example if you think of

```
(apply #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

The repeated summing of the arguments is done by the function `+` and not by `apply`.

This is different from

```
(reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

where the repeated call of the function `+` with two arguments is done by `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that I called arguments "parameters" (twice, no less! I've edited the question because the correct terminology is important for clarity). I'm familiar with `reduce`, but my only concern here was pushing the limits of the argument count, not actually processing the list. I will try `eval` and see if there are different results.